# How can I ignore empty arrays when i do a multiple get request with mostly string and numbers in mongo db

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the solution I am working right now:

```js
export const ProductsByFilter = async (req, res) => {

  const {a, b, c} = req.query

  let query = {}

  if (a) {
    query.a = a;
  }
  if (b) {
    query.b = b;
  }
  if (c) {
    query.c = c;
  }

  const products = await Product.find(query);

  res.status(200).json(products);
}
```

The thing is `a` is a String and `b` is a Number so they work ok when I do a multiple request even If one of them is empty, however `c` is an array and it doesn´t work , How can I make `c` query works too, using the same logic and keeping the multiple query request that can Ignore empty or null params.

Comment: try `if (c?.length) { query.c = c; }`

Comment: I appreciate your help but still is not working, I guess I have to change something in the find query, but still I don´t know.

Answer (score 0):

I use the code of the user who responded me but in order to make it fully functional I had to add $in as I present in the following code, then the query worked too with the array:

```
    export const ProductsByFilter = async (req, res) => {

    const {a, b, c} = req.query

    let query = {}

    if (a) {
       query.a = a;
    }
    if (b) {
       query.b = b;
    }
    if (c?.length) {
       query.c ={$in:c};
    }

    const products = await Product.find(query);

    res.status(200).json(products);
                                                          }
```